# Connecting to Azure SQL Server with AAD authentication using PyODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, azure-active-directory, pyodbc

**Environment:**
**Docker image**: python:2.7.14-stretch (which means Debian 9 as underlying OS)
Installed SQL Server ODBC driver for Debian 9 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
using pyodbc module
Connecting to Azure SQL Server with AAD authentication.

**Issue:**

First connection to DB is made perfectly fine. However any next connection to same DB or other DB is failed with below error:

> Exception::: ('08001', u'[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
>   for SQL Server]SSL Provider:
>   [error:140A90F1:lib(20):func(169):reason(241)] (-1)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')
>       Cannot connect to DB

Please note that this is issue with only when using AAD autnethcation mode. If I use simple sql server user, everything runs fine.

Below is the example code snippet.

```
db_list = [TEST_DB1, TEST_DB2]
sql_conn = None
for db in db_list:
    try:
        conn_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' \
                      'SERVER=' + <db_url> + \
                      ';DATABASE=' + <db_name> + \
                      ';UID=' + <db_username> + \
                      ';PWD=' + <db_password> + \
                      ';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'
        print conn_string
        sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:::", e
    print 'Cannot connect to DB' + str(sys.exc_info()[0])
    return None
sql_conn.cursor().execute(<some SQL Query>)
sql_conn.close()
```

Comment: In my case, this doesn't work because of two factor auth enabled for AD user